# Symfony handlerequest set datetime data one day below

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I have an app developed on Windows 8.1 enterprise using Symfony 2.6. When I deploy the app to a server using Debian 7.8, the `DateTime` members of an entity class are not proper saved.

Such problem doesn't happen when I run the app on windows. I started to find out the source of the problem and it seems that the statement

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

is the one causing the issue since I made a

```
var_dump($form->getData()->getMemberDate())
```

before and after the `handleRequest` and I got the date wrong on the after. Could someone tell me why is this happening? And more importantly how can I fix this?

Comment: what you mean by not proper saved ? compare the machine time on both environments, sounds like the debian machine is one day in front, e.g set the correct timezone in php.ini

Comment: What I meant for not been properly saved is that the date get saved 1 day before the real submitted data (For example if the user submits 2015-09-07 the DateTime entity member gets 2015-09-06 after the `$form->handleRequest($request);`) I checked the timezone on my php.ini (both the CLI and the apache), on the DB (MySQL) and they are right (America/Havana)

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem The server needed an apt-get upgrade I'm still learning when it comes to Linux I'm really sorry for all the fuss but I had to upload a new version of my app and I this ussue got the worst of me